# Как лучше передать указатель на массив?

Tags: ассемблер, указатели, переменные

Фасм. Лучше использовать только регистры в процедуре?
Вот есть у нас процедура где есть массивы и переменные. Их может быть не одна. А нам надо использовать при вызове разные массивы и разные переменные, РАЗНЫХ объектов.
Надо в самой процедуре использовать ТОЛЬКО регистры? Или лучше перезаписывать массивы перед вызовом?
Вообще лучше указатели менять.Но как лучше сделать? Если у нас в процедуре переменные?????
Можно заплатки сделать, как я показал в предыдущем вопросе. Но это, во первых переделывать под такое долго, а во вторых производительность падает, а в третьих увеличивается объём кода. В четвёртых читабельность падает.
Что посоветуете? Я уже не знаю даже

Comment: Если вас так беспокоит распределение переменных по регистрам, то, вероятно, следует перейти на язык более высокого уровня, наподобие C или C++. Оптимизирующий компилятор сам сделает это вместо вас.

Comment: Не вариант. Я пишу на этом языке

Answer (score 1):

В ассемблере ты можешь поступить так как тебе хочется, в этом и заключается прелесть этого языка, тебе никто не указ.

Что касается сути твоего вопроса то почитай __vectorcall